# Crop image in oval shape

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics

I am working on App in which i need to give an cropping option. Once i select the image from camera or gallery it should open on editing page where we have Oval image with zooming & moving option. Once we click on apply the captured image should cropped in oval shape.

Now following screen is from aviary sdk. But it has square cropping & in need the cropping in oval shape. I tried to customise it but not able to do so.

[image]

Can anyone suggest me the easiest or the best suitable way to implement this.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to mask an image? Do you know how to create an oval shape? Do you know how to draw into an image context?

Comment: Yes i know masking & i can create oval shape as well & draw into image context as well. But i want to know if there is an alternate & best suitable option available or not.

Comment: You can also use a clipping path, as described in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642136/uiimage-fill-transparent-part-with-another-image/22644165#22644165).

Comment: @Mayur what is the mistake in my code …. why u didn't use that ...

Comment: @Spynet because it was close to solution but not exactly as what i wanted on the other side i got exact working solution from Arvind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UIImage *)croppedPhoto {
    // For dealing with Retina displays as well as non-Retina, we need to check
    // the scale factor, if it is available. Note that we use the size of teh cropping Rect
    // passed in, and not the size of the view we are taking a screenshot of.
 CGRect croppingRect = CGRectMake(imgMaskImage.frame.origin.x,
imgMaskImage.frame.origin.y, imgMaskImage.frame.size.width,
imgMaskImage.frame.size.height);

    imgMaskImage.hidden=YES;

   if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(croppingRect.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(croppingRect.size);
    }

    // Create a graphics context and translate it the view we want to crop so
    // that even in grabbing (0,0), that origin point now represents the actual
    // cropping origin desired:
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -croppingRect.origin.x, -croppingRect.origin.y);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

    // Retrieve a UIImage from the current image context:
    UIImage *snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

   // Return the image in a UIImageView:
    return snapshotImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of masking you can perform or else you use the coco controls

**.h file:-**

```
@interface yourClass : UIImageView

@end
```

**.m file:-**

```
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    @implementation yourClass

    - (void)awakeFromNib
    {
        [super awakeFromNib];
        CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
        mask.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ovalMask.png"] CGImage];
        CGSize size = self.frame.size;
        mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        self.layer.mask = mask;
        [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    }

@end
```

Comment: can you please detail it how can i use this

Comment: take one black oval image and made a custom class