# Is it possible to Flood Fill image with another image in ios?

Tags: ios, image-processing

I have this example https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill
and read this post also: [UIImage fill transparent part with another image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642136/uiimage-fill-transparent-part-with-another-image)

But not getting result!!

I have one image. In this image when we touch any portion of that image fill that portion with another image instead of colour.

so if anybody have any idea or example than please help me.

I tried using

```
imageView.newcolor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern4.png"]];
```

but image fill with black color.

I want exactly this type of image, above flood fill example fill only single color in image but I want to fill with pattern or another image like below.

[image: img]

Comment: Please post what you have tried and the code you have

Comment: Please Open above image link that shows I want.

Comment: I have some issue @Taruna. Please share your solution for the same, if you solved.

Comment: Hello @Taruna, can you please share your solution if you found. I am facing the same issues as well. Thanks in advance.